# "Access violation reading location 0x0000000a." in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, access-violation, unhandled-exception

Im trying to call some nio functions from a DLL but keep getting the Access violation reading location error. This is the code that I have.

These are the functions that I want to call.

```
 typedef void ( *nio_read)(OUT IOSTAT  *pIoStat,
         IN OUT       IOVSPEC *pIov, 
               IN OUT       EGUREC  *pEgu, 
         IN OUT       IODATA  *pIoData );
 typedef void(*nio_paddr)(OUT IOSTAT *pIoStat, IN OUT IOVSPEC *pIov, 
        IN OUT EGUREC *pEgu, IN char *pszBuff);
 typedef void(*nio_tick_enable)(IOSTAT *pIoStat, IOVSPEC *pIov);
 typedef void(*nio_tick)(short int amount);
```

This is the main function

```
 int main(void)
 {
    nio_read _nio_read;
    nio_tick _nio_tick;
    nio_tick_enable _nio_tick_enable;
    nio_paddr _nio_paddr;
    IOSTAT  *pIoStat = (IOSTAT *)malloc(sizeof(IOSTAT));
    memset(pIoStat,0, sizeof(IOSTAT));

    IOVSPEC *pIov = (IOVSPEC *)malloc(sizeof(IOVSPEC));
    memset(pIov,0,sizeof(IOVSPEC));
    EGUREC  *pEgu =  (EGUREC *)malloc(sizeof(EGUREC));
    memset(pEgu,0,sizeof(EGUREC));
    IODATA  *pIoData = (IODATA *)malloc(sizeof(IODATA));
    memset(pIoData,0,sizeof(IODATA));;

          HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary("J91STSR.dll");


   if( hInstLibrary ) {
    _nio_read=(nio_read)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary,"nio_read");
    _nio_paddr=(nio_paddr)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary,"nio_paddr");
    _nio_tick=(nio_tick)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary,"nio_tick");
    _nio_tick_enable=(nio_tick_enable)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary,"nio_tick_enable");
    printf("testttt \n");
    }


if(_nio_read){
    (_nio_read)(pIoStat, pIov,pEgu,pIoData);

  }

  if( hInstLibrary ) {
    FreeLibrary(hInstLibrary );
  }
 }
```

I get the error at this line

```
 (_nio_read)(pIoStat, pIov,pEgu,pIoData);
```

I'm still new to c++ and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: You need to initialize _nio_read otherwise if(_nio_read) can be true even if hInstLibrary is null

Comment: All the structures you allocate (btw, why use `malloc`? why allocate dynamically in the first place?) you initialize to zero. That means any pointer in those structures are set to `NULL`. If the `nio_read` function doesn't expect a pointer to be `NULL` and dereferences that pointer then you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Does LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress succeed?

Comment: @drescherjm I initialized _nio_read with the command :  nio_read _nio_read;

Comment: No, there you define the variable `_nio_read`, but you do not *initialize* the variable. Local variables are always uninitialized (unless explicitly initialized), you need to initialize them yourself, and accessing an uninitialized variable leads to undefined behavior as its value will be indeterminate.

Comment: Yes they do @ Alex Farber and

Comment: How do I initialize it ten @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Assign to the variable. Either in the definition or afterwards (unconditionally). Like `int* p = 0;`, that definition initializes the pointer `p` to *null*.

Comment: I tried 'nio_read _nio_read = 0;' but that still gave the same error @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Then (re-)read my first comment.